# How i can load a directory as view in a controller function : Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, controller

I have a folder which contains some API files i have put whole folder into view directory now i want to load whole folder as a view not any single file.

For Example i have a folder name **review** so i want to load the whole folder as a view.

i have tried something but every time its added .php extension after the directory how i can do this: i have following function...

```
enter code here public function load_root(){
 $root_url = $this->load->view('/review/');
  }
```

Comment: u want to load all files at once from that folder??

Comment: actually i need whole directory as a path that i have to use as url.

Comment: Does it only contain .php files?

Comment: no its have all the other file like css images .

Answer (score 0):

use `scandir` to scan all the files in a folder.

```
$dir    = '/folder_name';
$files = scandir($dir);

print_r($files);// will print all the files inside the folder.
```

Use foreach, and load all the views in the folder.

Comment: i have to create a path as follows:

http://localhost/traffictack/index.php/user/load_root
this is my baseurl:
http://localhost/traffictack/index.php/

and i have a user as controller then in that controller i have a function load_root which have to load whole directory from view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load `helper('directory')`

Try

```
$this->load->helper('directory');
$files = directory_map('reviews')); // Directory Name here

foreach($files as $file)
{
    $this->load->view('/review/'.$file);
}
```

Note: The above code works fine for CodeIgniter 3+